# What is the most standard(/concise) way to compare the lists to check whether they have partial matches?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Suppose I have a case class that looks like the following

```
case class CaseClassX(a: String, b: Int, c: Boolean)
```

and two lists of same length containing this case class.

What is the most standard(/concise) way to compare the lists to check whether they have partial matches?
(Assuming that the lists are sorted)

i.e.
Comparison is carried out only on b and c, but not a

**Successful case:**

```
  Seq(
    CaseClassX("some text1", 1, true),
    CaseClassX("some text2", 2, false),
    CaseClassX("some text3", 3, true)
  )
```

*The above should match the following*

```
 Seq(
    CaseClassX("some text4", 1, true),
    CaseClassX("some text5", 2, false),
    CaseClassX("some text6", 3, true)
  )
```

**Failed case:**

```
  Seq(
    CaseClassX("some text1", 1, true),
    CaseClassX("some text2", 2, false),
    CaseClassX("some text3", 3, true)
  )
```

*The above should not match the following*

```
 Seq(
    CaseClassX("some text4", 1, true),
    CaseClassX("some text5", 2, true),
    CaseClassX("some text6", 3, true)
  )
```

Comment: Please give an example test case. For example, provide 2 input lists and what do you expect as a result.

Comment: Added example cases

Comment: By "match" you mean just returning `true/false`?

Comment: Can we assume that both lists are in order? So corresponding entries on both lists will have the same indexes?

Comment: yes, return true if successful(match) else false and you can assume they are sorted in order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd write a generic method like the following:

```
// this is good practice
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq

def matches[A, B](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[B])(comparer: (A, B) => Boolean): Boolean = xs.zip(ys).forall { case (x, y) => comparer(x, y) }

case class CaseClassX(a: String, b: Int, c: Boolean)

val xs = List(CaseClassX("hi", 42, false), CaseClassX("hello", 1, true)
val ys = List(CaseClassX("hi", 42, true), CaseClassX("hello", 1, false))

matches(xs, ys)((x, y) => x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b) //true
matches(xs, ys)((x, y) => x.a == y.c && x.c == y.c) //false
```

I edited it so that it is even more generic. No need to restrict the second parameter to `Seq[A]` so I added another type parameter and made it become `Seq[B]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could `zip` both sequences and then just use `forall`:

```
def partialMatch(seq1: Seq[CaseClassX], seq2: Seq[CaseClassX]): Boolean = (seq1, seq2)
  .zipped
  .forall {
     case (CaseClassX(_, b1, c1),CaseClassX(_, b2, c2)) => b1 == b2 && c1 == c2
  }
```